# Why does my laptop fan run all the time now?

Tags: laptop

I've been getting an error about a non-functional fan. After running Windows 10 LTSB for a few hours, I noticed the fan wasn't running and the laptop temperature was too high. I tried to keep using it, but it shutdown automatically (thermal shutdown?). I asked for help in the [HP forums](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Fan-has-stopped-working-What-do-I-need-to-do-now/td-p/6242925) and they told me to get a new fan, so I got a Noctua NT-NH1 thermal paste. I opened up the laptop, but was worried about damaging it, so I had a service person stop by.

He cleaned the existing thermal paste with cloth, and applied around ~15 mm length of thermal paste, with greater concentration on the GPU and CPU. On the Noctua cover, it suggests to apply paste of ~5mm length at the middle.

After starting the laptop, the new fan started running, but it runs all the time at low speed. Why can't it stop? I am not seeing any problem on the surface, but I don't want to leave it like this if it can decrease the laptop's life.

Reports:

[Specy](http://speccy.piriform.com/results/bvESduxzTeAzfqX5Y4PxMhi)

[HWiNFO64](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgSHsAUeSvVVglky6lF0NrFm87GY)

Comment: "Why can't it stop?" - Because you have replaced it with a fan that requires it work harder to keep your system cool

Comment: @Ramhound That's incorrect. OP replaced it with an identical fan. They made a typo. Noctua NT-NH1 is a thermal compound.

Comment: Did you end up purchasing this fan: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-For-HP-Pavilion-680551-001-CPU-cooling-fan-4-wires/32306710042.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10068_10084_10083_10080_10307_10082_10081_10110_10137_10175_10111_10060_10112_10155_10113_10114_10154_10056_10055_10054_10310_10059_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051-10050,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_4&btsid=8663cfc2-0def-45cb-8c54-d02c3858b5e4&algo_expid=d5e82775-6a17-4402-90d3-e1afa42768e5-0&algo_pvid=d5e82775-6a17-4402-90d3-e1afa42768e5 ?

Comment: No. I brought fan from ebay: http://www.ebay.in/itm/New-For-Hp-680551-001-Far3300epa-Laptop-CPU-Cooling-Fan-/391801378692?hash=item5b392e9784:g:yRMAAOSwLF1X2N9S Cost in ebay is less than that on Aliexpress.

Comment: Regardless it's the same P/N, correct? It won't take up any less power than your old fan would've if it actually worked

Comment: Yeah it has the same part number (= P/N?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your fan wasn't running at all before, it wasn't using any power. If the new fan is running, that means it's working. Your fans should never go completely off. Any laptop will run its' fans at 1% speed while the computer is active.

Chances are, you're not used to hearing a fan making noise at 1% of max speed.
Your old fan wasn't running at all as far as I know, so it's unexpected to you that it be as loud as it is.

As long as it's not running at its' max speed 100% of the time, it shouldn't drain your laptop's battery excessively.

Also, you should be able to adjust speed through [your graphics driver software](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-pavilion-g6-2200-notebook-pc-series/5296082/model/5340269/swItemId/ob-138637-1).

In addition, the "Noctua NT-NH1" is a type of thermal paste. I'm guessing you bought [this fan](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-For-HP-Pavilion-680551-001-CPU-cooling-fan-4-wires/32306710042.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10068_10084_10083_10080_10307_10082_10081_10110_10137_10175_10111_10060_10112_10155_10113_10114_10154_10056_10055_10054_10310_10059_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_10052_10053_10142_10107_10050_10051-10050,searchweb201603_1,ppcSwitch_4&btsid=8663cfc2-0def-45cb-8c54-d02c3858b5e4&algo_expid=d5e82775-6a17-4402-90d3-e1afa42768e5-0&algo_pvid=d5e82775-6a17-4402-90d3-e1afa42768e5) from AliExpress, as it seems from [your thread](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Fan-has-stopped-working-What-do-I-need-to-do-now/m-p/6248725/highlight/true#M409223) on the HP forums and a tube of Noctua NT-NH1 thermal compound. In which case, it is expected that your fan runs at a low speed at most times.

Comment: I have got into another problem. See here: [How to configure SpeedFan?](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-to-configure-speedfan/#post-026668c3-d640-4703-8ce5-35283fe5f6a4)

Comment: AMD HD graphics driver download link which you have given, seems to be only for windows 7. Is there any other way of controlling fan manually?